# UICollectionView added inside UITableViewCell programmatically, but doesn't appear?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, uicollectionviewcell

I have UItableView created from the storyboard and this how I use cellForRowAt indexPath func

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        let titleCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "titleCell", for: indexPath) as! MenuTableViewCell

        titleCell.label.text = newsTitle

        return titleCell
    }else if indexPath.row == 1 {
        let collectionViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "collectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! collectionViewCell

        return collectionViewCell
    }

    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    return cell
}
```

I have created this class for UICollectionView programmatically :

```
private class collectionViewCell : UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

private let reuseableCell = "CellId"

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseableCell)

}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
}


let imagesCollectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.horizontal
    let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    collectionView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    return collectionView
}()


func setupViews() {
    backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    addSubview(imagesCollectionView)

    imagesCollectionView.dataSource = self
    imagesCollectionView.delegate = self


    addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[v0]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": imagesCollectionView]))
    addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[v0]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": imagesCollectionView]))
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = UICollectionViewCell()
    cell.backgroundColor = .green
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: 100, height: frame.height - 68)
}
}
```

as you see I've changed the color of UICollectionView and it's cells, but nothing colored in UITableView.

and after I run the app nothing happened, so is there any mistake I've made here ?

Comment: have you set UICollectionView delegate and datasorse?

Comment: set up frame of collectionview  let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem like your `setupViews()` method is being called. Consider calling it in your initialisers.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this note, also I should register the cell fro UICollectionView

Comment: Yes good catch! Also as a side note: your `collectionViewCell` class name as such should be capitalised.

Comment: absolutely bro .

Answer (score -1):

You trying to subclass `UITableViewCell` in your `UICollectionViewCell`.

This:

```
private class collectionViewCell : UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate
```

Should be:

```
private class collectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate
```